# Print hostlist using ansible API

Tags: python, ansible

How do I get just the hostlist using ansible API. I want the equivalent of the below command using the ansible python API.

```
ansible all --list-host
```

**EDIT:**

Is this the right way?

```
inventory = ansible.inventory.Inventory(options.inventory)
for h in inventory.host_list():
    print h
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager

loader = DataLoader()

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=['PATH_TO_INVENTORY_FILE'])

variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

myhosts = variable_manager.get_vars()['groups']['all']
```

Please notice that PATH_TO_INVENTORY_FILE can be absolute or relative to the current directory, so you could do something like "./inventory/hosts"

Also be aware in there 'all' the hosts will be gathered. If you'd want to filter a specific group just specify the name of the group instead of 'all'.